# Convert a C printf(%c) to C#

Tags: c#, c, printf

I'm trying to convert this C printf to C#

```
printf("%c%c",(x>>8)&0xff,x&0xff);
```

I've tried something like this:

```
int x = 65535;

char[] chars = new char[2];
chars[0] = (char)(x >> 8 & 0xFF);
chars[1] = (char)(x & 0xFF);
```

But I'm getting different results.
I need to write the result to a file
so I'm doing this:

```
tWriter.Write(chars);
```

Maybe that is the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What results do you get with the C version, and what results do you get with the C# version?

Comment: for this value -> 65535
C returns -> ÿÿ
C# returns -> Ã¿Ã¿

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think that Ã¿ is the UTF-8 sequence for ÿ when interpreted as Windows-1252 instead of UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET, [char](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char(VS.71).aspx) variables are stored as unsigned 16-bit (2-byte) numbers ranging in value from 0 through 65535. So use this:

```
        int x = (int)0xA0FF;  // use differing high and low bytes for testing

        byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
        bytes[0] = (byte)(x >> 8);  // high byte
        bytes[1] = (byte)(x);       // low byte
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use a BinaryWriter than just do two writes:

```
bw.Write((byte)(x>>8));
bw.Write((byte)x);
```

Keep in mind that you just performed a Big Endian write. If this is to be read as an 16-bit integer by something that expects it in Little Endian form, swap the writes around.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I got it using the [Mitch Wheat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16076/mitch-wheat) suggestion and changing the TextWriter to BinaryWriter.

Here is the code

```
System.IO.BinaryWriter bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(System.IO.File.Open(@"C:\file.ext", System.IO.FileMode.Create));

int x = 65535;

byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
bytes[0] = (byte)(x >> 8);
bytes[1] = (byte)(x);

bw.Write(bytes);
```

Thanks to everyone.
Especially to Mitch Wheat.